# why crtl-C or ctrl-Z is not working in this program?

Tags: linux, process, kill, signals

While this process is running, I try to stop it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but neither of them work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    process();
}

void  process(void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 20000000; i++) {
        printf("hello world!\n");
    }
    
    printf("!!!!!!end of print!!!!!!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> work for me, either in a terminal window or in an Emacs shell buffer.

The reason it does not work for you may depend on the type of terminal you are using.  It may be that it is overwhelmed by the program's output and then it does not manage to process keyboard input.

Try this, and see if it solves your problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void  process(void)
{
  int   i;

  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      printf("hello world!\n");
      sleep(1);
    }

  printf("!!!!!!end of print!!!!!!\n");
}

void  main(void)
{
  process();
}
```